# What goes in the Sequelize "config file"?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm just starting out with Sequelize in Node.js and finding the documentation really lacking. I have a 'db' module in which I connect to the database via `Sequelize`, and this reads in configuration from an application-wide config file at `./config.json` relative to the root of my project. This is a nested configuration and extremely unlikely to be structured in the way that Sequelize wants a config file for the CLI.

Now I'm trying to use migrations and the documentation makes reference to a "config file". I know I can set the path to that config file, but what the heck do I put in it? It's not documented anywhere (that I've seen).

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/master/docs/README.md seems relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I read the code to figure it out. It's a flat structure. I just rebuild the config in a different format from my own config.

```
var config = require('./config');

module.exports = {
  database: config.database.name,
  username: config.database.user,
  password: config.database.pass,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  dialectModulePath: 'pg.js',
  host: config.database.host,
  port: config.database.port,
  pool: config.database.pool
};
```

Comment: So I see the "config file" is a js file in your example but I'm following a tutorial that tells me to name it `.sequelizerc`, shouldn't it be `.sequelizerc.js`???

Comment: @commonSenseCode .sequelizerc.js is not supported by Sequelize, even though its content is written in JavaScript, use .sequelizerc instead

Comment: Is it possible to store custom settings in there as well?

Comment: did you set up the define properties?

Answer (score 10):

There are more things you could put into a config file:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database.dbName, config.database.master.user,     config.database.master.password, {
    dialect: config.database.protocol,
    port: config.database.port,
    host: config.database.master.host,
    /* You could setup replication as well
    replication: {
     read: [
     {
       host: config.database.master.host,
       username: config.database.master.host,
       password: config.database.master.password
     },
     {
       host: config.database.master.host,
       username: config.database.master.host,
       password: config.database.master.password
     }
     ],
     write: {
       host: config.database.master.host,
       username: config.database.master.host,
       password: config.database.master.password
     }
     */
    },
    pool: {
        maxConnections: config.database.pool.maxConnections,
        maxIdleTime: config.database.pool.maxIdleTime
    },

    logging: false,
    define: {
        underscored: false,
        freezeTableName: false,
        syncOnAssociation: true,
        charset: 'utf8',
        collate: 'utf8_general_ci',
        classMethods: {method1: function() {}},
        instanceMethods: {method2: function() {}},
        timestamps: true
        schema: "prefix"
    }
}),
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the [documentation for the constructor](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js%7Esequelize#instance-constructor-constructor) describes all the options available on the config. As of 8/17/2022 (Sequelize v6; the current release).*

```
options.host    string  
optional
default: 'localhost'
The host of the relational database.

options.port    number  
optional
The port of the relational database.

options.username    string  
optional
default: null
The username which is used to authenticate against the database.

options.password    string  
optional
default: null
The password which is used to authenticate against the database.

options.database    string  
optional
default: null
The name of the database.

options.dialect string  
optional
The dialect of the database you are connecting to. One of mysql, postgres, sqlite, db2, mariadb and mssql.

options.dialectModule   string  
optional
default: null
If specified, use this dialect library. For example, if you want to use pg.js instead of pg when connecting to a pg database, you should specify 'require("pg.js")' here

options.dialectModulePath   string  
optional
default: null
If specified, load the dialect library from this path. For example, if you want to use pg.js instead of pg when connecting to a pg database, you should specify '/path/to/pg.js' here

options.dialectOptions  object  
optional
An object of additional options, which are passed directly to the connection library

options.storage string  
optional
Only used by sqlite. Defaults to ':memory:'

options.protocol    string  
optional
default: 'tcp'
The protocol of the relational database.

options.define  object  
optional
default: {}
Default options for model definitions. See Model.init.

options.query   object  
optional
default: {}
Default options for sequelize.query

options.schema  string  
optional
default: null
A schema to use

options.set object  
optional
default: {}
Default options for sequelize.set

options.sync    object  
optional
default: {}
Default options for sequelize.sync

options.timezone    string  
optional
default: '+00:00'
The timezone used when converting a date from the database into a JavaScript date. The timezone is also used to SET TIMEZONE when connecting to the server, to ensure that the result of NOW, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and other time related functions have in the right timezone. For best cross platform performance use the format +/-HH:MM. Will also accept string versions of timezones used by moment.js (e.g. 'America/Los_Angeles'); this is useful to capture daylight savings time changes.

options.clientMinMessages   string | boolean    
optional
default: 'warning'
(Deprecated) The PostgreSQL client_min_messages session parameter. Set to false to not override the database's default.

options.standardConformingStrings   boolean 
optional
default: true
The PostgreSQL standard_conforming_strings session parameter. Set to false to not set the option. WARNING: Setting this to false may expose vulnerabilities and is not recommended!

options.logging Function    
optional
default: console.log
A function that gets executed every time Sequelize would log something. Function may receive multiple parameters but only first one is printed by console.log. To print all values use (...msg) => console.log(msg)

options.benchmark   boolean 
optional
default: false
Pass query execution time in milliseconds as second argument to logging function (options.logging).

options.omitNull    boolean 
optional
default: false
A flag that defines if null values should be passed as values to CREATE/UPDATE SQL queries or not.

options.native  boolean 
optional
default: false
A flag that defines if native library shall be used or not. Currently only has an effect for postgres

options.replication boolean 
optional
default: false
Use read / write replication. To enable replication, pass an object, with two properties, read and write. Write should be an object (a single server for handling writes), and read an array of object (several servers to handle reads). Each read/write server can have the following properties: host, port, username, password, database

options.pool    object  
optional
sequelize connection pool configuration

options.pool.max    number  
optional
default: 5
Maximum number of connection in pool

options.pool.min    number  
optional
default: 0
Minimum number of connection in pool

options.pool.idle   number  
optional
default: 10000
The maximum time, in milliseconds, that a connection can be idle before being released.

options.pool.acquire    number  
optional
default: 60000
The maximum time, in milliseconds, that pool will try to get connection before throwing error

options.pool.evict  number  
optional
default: 1000
The time interval, in milliseconds, after which sequelize-pool will remove idle connections.

options.pool.validate   Function    
optional
A function that validates a connection. Called with client. The default function checks that client is an object, and that its state is not disconnected

options.pool.maxUses    number  
optional
default: Infinity
The number of times a connection can be used before discarding it for a replacement, used for eventual cluster rebalancing.

options.quoteIdentifiers    boolean 
optional
default: true
Set to false to make table names and attributes case-insensitive on Postgres and skip double quoting of them. WARNING: Setting this to false may expose vulnerabilities and is not recommended!

options.transactionType string  
optional
default: 'DEFERRED'
Set the default transaction type. See Sequelize.Transaction.TYPES for possible options. Sqlite only.

options.isolationLevel  string  
optional
Set the default transaction isolation level. See Sequelize.Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS for possible options.

options.retry   object  
optional
Set of flags that control when a query is automatically retried. Accepts all options for retry-as-promised.

options.retry.match Array   
optional
Only retry a query if the error matches one of these strings.

options.retry.max   number  
optional
How many times a failing query is automatically retried. Set to 0 to disable retrying on SQL_BUSY error.

options.typeValidation  boolean 
optional
default: false
Run built-in type validators on insert and update, and select with where clause, e.g. validate that arguments passed to integer fields are integer-like.

options.operatorsAliases    object  
optional
String based operator alias. Pass object to limit set of aliased operators.

options.hooks   object  
optional
An object of global hook functions that are called before and after certain lifecycle events. Global hooks will run after any model-specific hooks defined for the same event (See Sequelize.Model.init() for a list). Additionally, beforeConnect(), afterConnect(), beforeDisconnect(), and afterDisconnect() hooks may be defined here.

options.minifyAliases   boolean 
optional
default: false
A flag that defines if aliases should be minified (mostly useful to avoid Postgres alias character limit of 64)

options.logQueryParameters  boolean 
optional
default: false
A flag that defines if show bind parameters in log.
```

*Note many of these properties like `pool` and `logging` are mentioned in the other answers. [@siyang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25151089/1175496) describes the `define` property directly, but the documentation also covers that (see the `options` property) (TODO: insert documentation link to the static method init)

By the way, I was trying to solve the [issue of "Resource request timed out" while using Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8133)  to make some PostgreSQL updates, that's why I shared these links to documentation; tweaking the `pool` property may help you if you have this problem.

**EDIT**

I later noticed that some properties are missing, these options are combined with the config database/username/password, to create a larger sequelize.config, TODO: confirm the below code is still relevant; find it in github/sequelize current code; which  includes some values not described above, including `ssl` and `defaultTimezone`.

```
this.config = {
  database: config.database,
  username: config.username,
  password: config.password,
  host: config.host || this.options.host,
  port: config.port || this.options.port,
  pool: this.options.pool,
  protocol: this.options.protocol,
  native: this.options.native,
  ssl: this.options.ssl,
  replication: this.options.replication,
  dialectModulePath: this.options.dialectModulePath,
  keepDefaultTimezone: this.options.keepDefaultTimezone,
  dialectOptions: this.options.dialectOptions
};
```

Comment: Links provided are not available anymore. In the config, where would the `define` go to set `paranoid: true` and `unserscored: true`

Comment: Hi @myselfmiqdad here is an updated link. Note this link includes an example which shows how `options.define` is itself an object: https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js~sequelize#instance-constructor-constructor

Comment: I'm trying to make it work with sequelize-cli, i have a `dbconfig.js` which is set up in `.sequelizerc` as `'config': path.resolve('src', 'dbconfig.js'),` and have the `username, password, host, etc` in the config, however, when i set up the `define` attribute, it's not picked up. Would you be familiar with the structure of it?

Comment: Hi @myselfmiqdad I'm not sure, but please  confirm this. Can you paste me the contents of your `dbconfig.js` file? The `username` & `password` is at the *top level*, there should also be `options` property at the *top level*; inside `options` is the `define` property. Inside the `define` property are the `define` configurations...

Comment: I've created an issue on their GitHub: https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/1139

Comment: Beautiful issue @myselfmiqdad thanks for sharing